# Deserializing a particular node of XMLDocument object

Tags: c#

I have the below piece of code that accepts an XMLDocument object and a xml of the format mentioned below the code. I want to read the values of  4 tags present in the bouding box:

SouthLatitude, etc

```
    public static void readXML(XmlDocument document)
    {

        if (document == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("document");
        }




        XmlNode specificNode = document.SelectSingleNode("/Response/ResourceSets/ResourceSet/Resources/Location/BoundingBox");

        if (specificNode != null)
        {
            XmlNodeReader specificNodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(specificNode);

            while (specificNodeReader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(specificNodeReader.Value);
            }
        }
     }
```

The xml looks like this:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
  <Copyright>Copyright © 2012 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.</Copyright> 
  <BrandLogoUri>http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png</BrandLogoUri> 
  <StatusCode>200</StatusCode> 
  <StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription> 
  <AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode> 
  <TraceId>f651e16fe1204e12b848084d73f5148d|SINM001008|02.00.83.1900|SINMSNVM001115, SINMSNVM001124</TraceId> 
- <ResourceSets>
- <ResourceSet>
  <EstimatedTotal>1</EstimatedTotal> 
- <Resources>
- <Location>
  <Name><Some Name</Name> 
- <Point>
  <Latitude>47.640570402145386</Latitude> 
  <Longitude>-122.12937377393246</Longitude> 
  </Point>
- <BoundingBox>
  <SouthLatitude>47.636707684574709</SouthLatitude> 
  <WestLongitude>-122.13701709146854</WestLongitude> 
  <NorthLatitude>47.644433119716062</NorthLatitude> 
  <EastLongitude>-122.12173045639638</EastLongitude> 
  </BoundingBox>
  <EntityType>Address</EntityType> 

  </Location>
  </Resources>
  </ResourceSet>
  </ResourceSets>
  </Response>
```

Can someone point out, what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you give the usage example in this particular case?

Comment: Your XML is not valid as you can not use numbers for elements.

Comment: It might also help if you posted a more detailed XML example if you don't find the current answer helpful. And exactly what value you are trying to extract from it.

Comment: I have posted the actual xml

Comment: The word 'deserializing' in the title might be misleading - it seems you just need the value of specific nodes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your actual `xml` has a namespace, you will need to include it in any `Xpath` queries you use. Since you already have the xml loaded in an `XmlDocument`, you don't need an `XmlReader`

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("ms", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1");
XmlNode boundingBoxNode = document.SelectSingleNode("/ms:Response/ms:ResourceSets/ms:ResourceSet/ms:Resources/ms:Location/ms:BoundingBox", nsm);

if (boundingBoxNode != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(boundingBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("ms:SouthLatitude", nsm).InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(boundingBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("ms:NorthLatitude", nsm).InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(boundingBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("ms:EastLongitude", nsm).InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(boundingBoxNode.SelectSingleNode("ms:WestLongitude", nsm).InnerText);
}
```

You can also do this in Linq to Xml:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1";

var boundingBox = document
                .Descendants(ns + "Response")
                .Descendants(ns + "ResourceSets")
                .Descendants(ns + "ResourceSet")
                .Descendants(ns + "Resources")
                .Descendants(ns + "Location")
                .Descendants(ns + "BoundingBox");

if (boundingBox != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(boundingBox.Descendants(ns + "SouthLatitude").First().Value);
    Console.WriteLine(boundingBox.Descendants(ns + "NorthLatitude").First().Value);
    Console.WriteLine(boundingBox.Descendants(ns + "EastLongitude").First().Value);
    Console.WriteLine(boundingBox.Descendants(ns + "WestLongitude").First().Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        XmlNode specificNode = document.SelectSingleNode("/Response/ResourceSets/ResourceSet/Resources/Location/BoundingBox");
        if (specificNode != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode child in specificNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(child.InnerText);
            }
        }
```

Should do the trick. Of course a lot of credit goes to Henk Holterman in his earlier answer.